# Spark: configuration file 'metrics.properties'

Tags: java, apache-spark, metrics

Spark's configuration file (useful to retrieve metrics), namely `/conf/metrics.properties`, states what follows:

> Within an instance, a "source" specifies a particular set of grouped metrics.
>     there are two kinds of sources:
>
> 1. Spark internal sources, like MasterSource, WorkerSource, etc, which will collect a Spark component's internal state. Each instance is paired with a Spark source that is added automatically.
> 2. Common sources, like JvmSource, which will collect low level state. These can be added through configuration options and are then loaded using reflection.

Some examples follow, as

```
master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

Yet, there is no example explaining how to get metrics from other sources as `MasterSource` or `WorkerSource`, and just replacing `JvmSource` is not doing the trick.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MasterSource or WorkerSource --which are both internal sources-- are automatically traced by metrics, so there is no need to specify this explicitly.

For instance,

> master.sink.cvs.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.CsvSink

will output master instance metrics to `/tmp` directory each 10 seconds.